# How can I create a link with popup window appearing on clicking the link

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I want to create a link in sugarcrm module and on clicking this link a popup window appears with a list of users and select a particular user from the popup window.

Can any one tell me how to create a link and pop up in sugarcrm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact code, but there is a popup helper built into sugar (do a search for SQS in the existing code).  If you look at the code at any of the pop fields already in place (like accounts, or opportunities), there is a fairly simple couple of lines of JS to make the popup box, and set the return function.  Then it is just a matter of setting fields with the returned information.

-I know it's not too specific but hopefully this will help guide you.